# How to point a domain at Siteground to an app hosted by Heroku?

Tags: heroku, dns, heroku-toolbelt

A while back I purchased a domain through siteground. I have a build a react app that I just deployed at Heroku and want to point the domain located at siteground to the app. However I'm having some issues with it. I need to add it to the cname record but I have no idea how. I have tried it now by making a cname record for [www].example.nl with resolves to erwer1234adadad.herokudns .com which is the (*.example.nl) however it's still not working (gyazo.com/c321dd078fa34343a696074c4c4fa884)

I contacted the siteground support but they think I speak french.

Comment: "it gives me only one target however I require two at Siteground" Are you sure you're not accidentally putting the Heroku record into the nameservers list?

Comment: Yeah I did that before I was literally just editing the content when I was writing it! I need to add it to the cname record but I have no idea how. I have tried it now by making a cname record for [www].example.nl with resolves to erwer1234adadad.herokudns .com which is the (*.example.nl) however it's still not working (https://gyazo.com/c321dd078fa34343a696074c4c4fa884)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion site ground doesn't support naked/root domain pointing so I would suggest to use any service like cloudflare or dns simple , if you don't want to use external service you can go ahead with point dns a heroku addon.

Please follow the below-mentioned steps to configure pointDNS

1.Go to APP -> settings-> under domain section add below domains
domainname.com
[www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com).
2. Go to resources-> add PointDNS addon,
Verify by clicking on pointDNS
3. Copy all NS records from dataplug to pointDNS
4. Update NS issued by pointDNS (dns8.pointhq.com,dns12.pointhq.com) in siteground